# How to assign ASP.NET hidden field value to JavaScript variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Following is the code snippets taken from 
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx

```
// pre-selected tags
values: [
    'javascript',
    'css',
    'jquery'];
```

I want to assign `values` with some hidden field or C# variable, please help as I don't have expertise with JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to pass the values to code-behind (c#)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a public property and use it in your HTML like the following...

**C# (Added per/comments)**

```
public string Choices { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] choices = new string[] { "'Choice 1'", "'Choice 2'", "'Choice 3'" };
    Choices = String.Join(",", choices);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var values = [<%= Choices %>];
</script>
```

NOTE: I put single quotes around the values since JavaScript requires the them to recognize the value as part of a string array ( **Valid** = ['value','value']  /  **Invalid** = [value,value] ).

Comment: In the definition of `MyProperty`, you should declare and initialize a C# array and invoke `return String.Join(",", myArray);`

Comment: You can do better. You can create and return the joined array of choices from the `Choices` property and do away with the setter. For example: `public string Choices { get { var choices = new [] {"'choice1'", "'choice2'", "'choice3'"}; return String.Join(",", choices); } }`

Comment: That's not better, that's just hard coding the logic in the getter which makes the property rigid and inflexible.  Since you don't know how they'll set the value(s) in code, it's better to leave it open to their own implementation.  Using a simple property is also much easier for a novice to understand.

Comment: That's where refactoring comes into play. The idea is to keep the String.Join away from the Page_Load. That's my only complaint since that logic belongs in the property, not the Page_Load. For example, what if the list of values changes. Then you'll end up with a second String.Join, which violates the "DRY" principle.

Answer (score 0):

hidden:

```
values: [
        $('hidden1').val(),
        $('hidden2').val(),
        $('hidden3').val()];
```

or c# (mvc):

```
values: [
        '@model.var1',
        '@model.var2',
        '@model.var3'];
```

Comment: This solution is not flexible and doesn't address the problem.